# How to make my form work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm a beginner at web design, and I've just made my first site using HTML, CSS and a little bit of javascript.   However, how can I make the button fully function in PHP, so that if the user enters "1234"  The user can click "search" which will open a separate page that is Google.com.   I don't know a lot of PHP so I don't know where to start.   Any help would be really apperciated ;)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400);

.webdesigntuts-workshop {
 background: #151515;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop:before,
.webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
 content: '';
 display: block; 
 height: 1px;
 left: 50%;
 margin: 0 0 0 -400px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 800px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop:before {
 background: #444;
 background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #444, #151515);
 top: 192px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop:after {
 background: #000;
 background: linear-gradient(left, #151515, #000, #151515); 
 top: 191px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop form {
 background: #111;
 background: linear-gradient(#1b1b1b, #111);
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #272727;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 0px;
 margin: 150px auto 0;
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input {
 background: #222; 
 background: linear-gradient(#333, #222); 
 border: 1px solid #444;
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
 color: #888;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
 width: 200px;
}

.ie .webdesigntuts-workshop input {
 line-height: 40px;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #888;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:-moz-placeholder {
   color: #888;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus {
 animation: glow 800ms ease-out infinite alternate;
 background: #222922;
 background: linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
 border-color: #393;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
 color: #efe;
 outline: none;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
 color: #efe;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #efe;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop button {
 background: #222;
 background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 1px solid #444;
 border-left-color: #000;
 border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
 width: 80px;
} 

.webdesigntuts-workshop button:hover,
.webdesigntuts-workshop button:focus {
 background: #292929;
 background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
 color: #5f5;
 outline: none;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop button:active {
 background: #292929;
 background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 1px #222;
 top: 1px;
}

@keyframes glow {
    0% {
  border-color: #393;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,255,0,.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
    } 
    100% {
  border-color: #6f6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,255,0,.6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,255,0,.4), 0 2px 0 #000;
    }
}
```

```html
<?php>






?>




<section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
 <form action="" method="">      
  <input type="search" placeholder="Enter your assigned number">       
  <button>Search</button>
 </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without `PHP`:

```
<section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
    <form action="https://www.google.com/search">           
        <input name="q" type="search" placeholder="Enter your assigned number">             
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</section>
```